# Scope of Data-Analysis Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I added the "data-analysis" tag to the question [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/can-post-processing-use-toposet-and-createpatch-without-screwing-up-the-results) since I felt it was the best fit for the author's request of a "post-processing" tag.

While I see those two terms as almost identical, I was wondering if the community saw them as such.  Data-analysis lends itself to experimental data and post-processing to computational results.  Are the two terms interchangeable and therefore is my use of the data-analysis tag  appropriate, or do we need a separate post-processing tag?